# Apache Velocity: ReourceNotFoundException in simple example

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to use velocity in my project. I am referring code from [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html#resources). My code doesn't do much except it creates a html page with a message.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.init();

        Template t = ve.getTemplate("seat.html");

        VelocityContext vc = new VelocityContext();
        vc.put("message", "Hello Velocity");

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(vc, sw);

        System.out.println(sw);
}
```

My template file `seat.html` is in the same folder as the class which contains this method as well as in the src folder of the project. This didn't work, so I tried to refer using absolute pathname. But that didn't work either. I also tried to configure velocity using `FilePathLoader` and `Properties` but I suppose this simple example should work as demonstrated in the [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html#resources) (referred above).

Folder structure:

```
velocity-test
    `-- src
        |-- bean
        |-- core
        |   |-- Application.java
        |   `-- seat.html
        `-- seat.html
```

Excception:

```
SEVERE: ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'seat.html' in any resource loader.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'seat.html'
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1514)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.getTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:373)
    at core.Application.main(Application.java:16)
```

There are few more questions on SO with answers but all those use some properties to configure velocity engine; which I don't want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ve.getTemplate("./src/seat.html");`.

Comment: @Satya Thanks! It works. Maybe you should post it as answer so I can accept it. I guess [doc](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/developer-guide.html#configuring_resource_loaders) states the default resource loader if `FilePathResourceLoader` and and default directory is current directory is incorrect then?

Comment: I didn't understand you question. @SureshS

Comment: The documentation says that: "`FileResourceLoader` is the default loader, and is configured, by default to get templates from the 'current directory'". Current directory is the folder where I have my `Application.java` class. Whereas the default directory is project's root directory. @Satya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change to

```
ve.getTemplate("./src/seat.html");
```